# Getting the names of the first n files without listing all of them in linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I know it is possible to list the first n files in a directory by simply typing:
`ls | head -n` where n is the number of files to be listed. However the problem is the directory I'm trying to run this at is full with thousands of files causing this action to be very slow (takes a couple of minutes) while all I wanted was just the names of the first files.

Is there any way of achieving the desired behavior? and how?

Comment: when you say first 5,  first based on what type of sorting?

Comment: Have you tried `ls -f1 | head -5`? Is it also too slow?

Comment: @nosid it is a lot faster with ls -f1 which is good for me. thanks~. But what if I wanted it sorted by name?

Comment: @shaunstone I didn't need any kind of sort so nosid helped me with this one. However what if I wanted it sorted by name? any way to make it faster?

Comment: @user2773143 So just remove color? `ls --color=no` And probably do `type ls` and check which other options you have by default/disable them.

Comment: You cannot not sort it, even when you don't specify a sort order they are sorted in a certain way. `coreutils` `ls` *does* sort by name by default.

Comment: Check out man page of `find`, it probably has switches for giving only N first matches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind about the ordering of the files..

You need to call the underlying libc opendir/readdir functions as this perl example shows

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

opendir(my $dh, ".") || die "can't opendir . : $!";
for (1..10) {
    $filename=readdir($dh);
    print "$filename\n";
}
```

or as a oneliner, which you *could* call from a shell script

```
perl -le 'opendir($d, "."); print scalar readdir($d) for (1..10);'
```

`ls -l |head` gives files in alphabetic order though which this cannot do.  All the files have to be read to get alphabetic ordering

Comment: Thanks. works well~ Isn't there a need to do closedir($d) in the end to release the handle?

Comment: @user2773143 It's not needed to explicitly close as once the variable holding the handle goes out of scope it gets freed.